# TimePicker reverse 24 hour data

Tags: android

Good day!

I have a Dialog class that contains TimePicker. TimePicker is set for 24hour mode. **When i pick time with hour < 12 - Picker returns it with +12 hours more**.

For example -

> i've set 07:25 - returns 19:25. And vise-versa
>
> if i set 19:43 - returns 07:42. And
>
> if i set 12:01, for example - TimePicker returns idiotic 24:01.

What's problem with this tool?

Here the full code of my Dialog class:

```
public class TimePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "time";

    @Bind(R.id.pickerTime_timePicker) TimePicker timePicker;

    //// DialogFragment methods

    @Override @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picker_time, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(view)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.time_picker_dialog_label))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }

    //// Private methods

    private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, getTimeFromTimePicker(timePicker));

        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }

    private Date getTimeFromTimePicker(TimePicker timePicker) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line,

```
timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

below,

```
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

which will set the current time corretly.
Let me know if it works for you...

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you should use calendar.set(Calendar.**HOUR_OF_DAY**, timePicker.getCurrentHour());

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. I should notice that my current time on device is 13:33. But when i start TimePicker it sets 01:33 on scrollers. 24hour mode is on.

Comment: That's strange. I copy and pasted your code into my project and it works fine. Except if I call caledar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) it returns 1 intead of 13. Which can be fixed by setting HOUR_OF_DAY, not HOUR. Maybe you set time to timePicker somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)
The provided example works for everyone, no need to bind something. Why do you need that extra logic inside the dialog? It should be responsible for picking the time. The other logic should be in your controller.